# Java: run a method periodcally using timer

Tags: java, timer

I've a Java project which is main create an instance of a class (ThreadClient) that extends Thread. I would need that ThreadClient.run starts 2 timers to run periodically 2 methods of the ThreadClient class.

The examples I found in internet just show that the timer can start the run method of an instance of a classe that exteds the Thread class.
I woundln't need to create a new class, just to run 2 methods of the same class that creates the timers.
Something like C# does:

```
public class ThreadClient 
{
    private Timer _timer; 

    public ThreadClient() {
        Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Method _timer_Elapsed belongs to the class that creates the timer.

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Comment: so you are stuck at ? (pun intended !)

Comment: What's your question? Do you have one, or is this just a rant about Java not being C#? Java has anonymous classes and lambdas. Learn using them.

Comment: Also, you should rather use a ScheduledExecutorService: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool-int-

Comment: The question was: is there a way to run methods of a class using timer created within the same class or a time can just run the run() method of antoher class?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I finally reached my goal:

```
    // Timer to process sales
    TimerTask ttProcessSales = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            processSales();
        }
    };
    Timer tProcessSales = new Timer();
    tProcessSales.schedule(ttProcessSales, 0, this._processTaskTimeInterval);

    // Timer to process tasks
    TimerTask ttProcessTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            processTasks();             
        }
    }; 
    Timer tProcessTasks = new Timer();
    tProcessTasks.schedule(ttProcessTask, 0, this._processTaskTimeInterval);
```

In this way I can run 2 methods of the class using timers without create new class for every method I needed to execute.